# Is there any way to track all costs for a specific Compute Engine Machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I find it really hard to control my GCP costs considering the invoice has a lot if items that are not easily linked to a specific machine. Is there any way to do this?

I have tried the billing reports, but I can only get the detail by SKU (XX RAM or YY vCPUs) but its really hard to link this SKU to specific Machines.

For clarity, I wish to know to total cost (sum of all SKUs) of each specific Machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Comment: Do you work for Google?

Comment: No. None of us do. That's why this is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [labels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources). When you label a resource, such as a VM, the charges for that resource will be marked with your label in the detailed billing export. This export can be configured to write to either [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) or [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file).

You can label each machine individually (which sounds like it would cover your case), or groups of resources. One common practice is to put different labels for production and testing, allowing you to track and search the different environments.

Once the labels are configured to your liking and the export is enabled, you'll be able to query and summarize the data based on the labels you've set.

To JJJ's point, you may consider using GCP's [billing support chat](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) in the future if you have more billing issues.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. I'll give it a try. And yes, I contacted google before posting here. The agent actually recommended me to ask here because she couldn't help me.